# How to automate changing parameters given a list of values for ARIMA

Tags: r, loops, data-manipulation, forecast

A fully reproducible example.

```
library(forecast)
date = seq(as.Date("2019/01/01"), by = "month", length.out = 48)

productB = rep("B",48)
productB = rep("B",48)
productA = rep("A",48)
productA = rep("A",48)

subproducts1=rep("1",48)
subproducts2=rep("2",48)
subproductsx=rep("x",48)
subproductsy=rep("y",48)

b1 <- c(rnorm(30,5), rep(0,18))
b2 <- c(rnorm(30,5), rep(0,18))
b3 <-c(rnorm(30,5), rep(0,18))
b4 <- c(rnorm(30,5), rep(0,18))
```

Created the dataframe below

```
dfone <- data.frame("date"= rep(date,4),
            "product"= c(rep(productB,2),rep(productA,2)),
            "subproduct"= 
c(subproducts1,subproducts2,subproductsx,subproductsy),
            "actuals"= c(b1,b2,b3,b4))

export_df <- split(dfone[1:4], dfone[3])
```

## Creation of data frames based off UNIQUE SUBPRODUCTS

```
dummy_list <- split(dfone[1:4], dfone[3]) %>% lapply( function(x) 
x[(names(x) %in% c("date", "actuals"))])
dummy_list <-  lapply(dummy_list, function(x) { x["date"] <- NULL; x })


list_dfs <- list()
for (i in 1:length(unique(dfone$subproduct))) {
  #assign(paste0("df", i), as.data.frame(dummy_list[[i]]))
  list_dfs <-append(list_dfs,dummy_list[[i]])
}

combined_dfs <- Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all = TRUE,  
by='date'), list(list_dfs))
```

Creating the time series

```
list_ts <- lapply(list_dfs, function(t) 
ts(t,start=c(2019,1),end=c(2021,6), frequency = 12)) %>%
  lapply( function(t) ts_split(t,sample.out=(0.2*length(t))))    # 
creates my train test split
list_ts <- do.call("rbind", list_ts)  #Creates a list of time series
```

How can I automatically create it so m1 to m6 is created automatically in the global environment? Notice how the first argument order = is the same and the 2nd argument it varies. After we use up all of the values of the 2nd order, we move on to the next element in the first argument's order.

```
m1<- lapply(list_ts[1: 
(length(list_ts)/2)], function(x)
 forecast::forecast(arima(x,order=c(1,1,1),seasonal=list(order=c(0,1,0),
period=12)) ,h=24))

m1<- lapply(m1, "[",  c("mean"))

m2<- lapply(list_ts[1: 
(length(list_ts)/2)], function(x)
 forecast::forecast(arima(x,order=c(1,1,1),seasonal=list(order=c(1,0,0),
period=12)) ,h=24))

m2<- lapply(m2"[",  c("mean"))

 m3<- lapply(list_ts[1: 
(length(list_ts)/2)], function(x)
 forecast::forecast(arima(x,order=c(1,1,1),seasonal=list(order=c(0,0,0),
period=12)) ,h=24))

m3<- lapply(m3"[",  c("mean"))


 m4<- lapply(list_ts[1: 
(length(list_ts)/2)], function(x)
 forecast::forecast(arima(x,order=c(0,0,0),seasonal=list(order=c(0,1,0),
period=12)) ,h=24))

m4<- lapply(m4, "[",  c("mean"))

m5<- lapply(list_ts[1: 
(length(list_ts)/2)], function(x)
 forecast::forecast(arima(x,order=c(0,0,0),seasonal=list(order=c(1,0,0),
period=12)) ,h=24))

m5<- lapply(m5"[",  c("mean"))

 m6<- lapply(list_ts[1: 
(length(list_ts)/2)], function(x)
 forecast::forecast(arima(x,order=c(0,0,0),seasonal=list(order=c(0,0,0),
period=12)) ,h=24))

m6<- lapply(m6"[",  c("mean"))
```

I'd want to do something with this

```
n1 <- ((0,0,0),(1,1,1))
where each element of n1 is (0,0,0)... etc
n2 <- ((0,1,0),(1,0,1),(0,0,0))

out<- lapply(seq_along(n1), function(i) {
   m<- lapply(list_ts[1: 
(length(list_ts)/2)], function(x) 
       forecast::forecast(arima(x,order=c(0,0,0),seasonal=list(order=c(1,0,0),
period=12)),h=24)
    m1<- 
 lapply(m1, "[", "mean")
  assign(paste0("m1", i), 
m1, envir = .GlobalEnv)
 m1})
```

Comment: Please check the updated solution

Comment: This works thanks again. I will try to force some errors to see what happens, when I do I will upvote your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We create two `list` with `vector`s as elements ('n1', 'n2').  Do the `expand.grid` to create a two column data.frame with combination of those `list`s

```
n1 <- list(c(0,0,0), c(1,1,1))
n2 <- list(c(1,0,0),c(0, 1, 0),c(0,0,0))
dat_n <- expand.grid(n1 = n1, n2 = n2)
```

Loo over the sequence of rows of 'dat_n', extract the `list` corresponding to those columns `[[i]]` and specify in the `order`

```
out <- lapply(seq_len(nrow(dat_n)), function(i) {
      m <- lapply(list_ts[1:(length(list_ts)/2)], function(x)  {
         tryCatch({forecast::forecast(arima(x, order = dat_n$n1[[i]],
           seasonal=list(order = dat_n$n2[[i]],
           period=12)),h=24)
           }, error = function(err) return(data.frame(mean = NA_real_))
           
           )})
     m <- lapply(m, "[", "mean")
   assign(paste0("m", i), m, envir = .GlobalEnv)
    m
  })
```

The code was also wrapped in a `tryCatch` - in case there are some forecasting errors, it will return `NA`

-checking for objects in the global env

```
ls(pattern = '^m\\d$')
[1] "m1" "m2" "m3" "m4" "m5" "m6"
```

Comment: Ok so if I have a forecast that returns a NA_forecast, is there way to delete every single m object that has that?

Comment: @chriswang123456  You may delete that before the assign i..e `m <- lapply(m, "[", "mean");i1 <- !sapply(m, function(x) all(is.na(x))); assign(paste0("m", i[i1]), m[i1], envir = .GlobalEnv); m})`

Comment: This works, but some of the outputs now have 3 elements instead of 4 which duplicates the first element For the values that are NA'd can we actually instead just make them 0's instead of removing them all together?

Comment: Or if it easier, we can remove lists from our global environment that is not a list of 4 starting with m

Comment: In that case you may change `m` as `m <- lapply(m, function(x) if(all(is.na(x))) 0 else x)`

Comment: @chriswang123456 that is also posssible.  once you create the objects `v1 <- ls(pattern = '^m\\d$'); rm(list = v1[sapply(mget(v1), function(x) lengths(x) != 4)])`

Comment: Just to make sure for your m <- lapply(m, function(x) if(all(is.na(x))) 0 else x) solution, we take the original solution and add that after  m <- lapply(m, "[", "mean")? That seems to work right now, just making sure.

Comment: @chriswang123456 yes, it is after extracing the `mean`.  It is confusing only because we are using the ssame object for updating. thanks for confirming

Comment: Yeah, I think it works as intended. Thank you again.